# How to align <ruby> text with <rb> instead of <rt>?

Tags: html, css

What css code should I use to align  text according to  instead of ?

I have tried using position: absolute on  yet it doesn't work.

Example(Notice the spacing between those annotation is the same but not the their bases):

```css
ruby{font-size: 20px;}
```

```html
<ruby>我<rt>1</rt>係<rt>2222222</rt>香<rt>33</rt>港<rt>444</rt>人<rt>5555</rt></ruby>
```

I expect aligning the text with its bases instead of those text annotation.  How can I achieve this  Thank you.

Comment: Could you upload a picture or anything of the desired result?

Comment: Check out this answere https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877801/9016196