# Bold letter on ruby element moves everything above this letter

Tags: html, css

I found a great solution to adjust the vertical position of ruby text on this post:

[Adjust the vertical positioning of ruby text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680695/adjust-the-vertical-positioning-of-ruby-text/71394771#71394771)

But when I try to put one letter bold inside ruby element everything go above the bold letter, Is there a solution for this?

```css
ruby {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  text-align: center;
}

rt {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
わたしの　<ruby><strong>会</strong>社<rt>かいしゃ</rt></ruby>です。
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't see the problem? I'm using Firefox right now.

Comment: I just check it and is not Ok on Firefox as well, what I want is this Kanji bold 会 and next to it this other Kanji 社 and over both of them the Hiragana かいしゃ, in all cases (Chorem or Firefox) what I see is this bold 会, over this one, the other Kanji 社 and over the last one the Hiragana lecture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```css
body {
  font-size: 28px;
}

ruby {
  font-family: 'Yu Gothic Bold';
}

rt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  line-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<p>Hola　<ruby><rt>かいしゃかきくけこ</rt><strong>会</strong>社 
</ruby></p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).